# Compilar string como um código

Tags: eval, vbscript

Tenho uma string em VBScript que eu preciso que seja executada como um código, como faria isso?

Li alguns artigos sobre Eval e Execute Statement porém não achei uma explicação clara ou não entendi corretamente...

por exemplo:

Dim str

str = "MsgBox "Olá mundo""

Como compilar essa string como código?

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: O fato é que VBScript é uma linguagem iterpretada e não compilada. Veja se isto te ajuda: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_eval.asp

Answer (score 2):

Se você quiser executar uma instrução que não retorna um valor, use `Execute`, exemplo:

```
Option Explicit

Dim mensagem
Dim codigo

mensagem = "Oi!!!"
codigo = "MsgBox mensagem"

Execute codigo
```

Se o seu código retornar um valor, use o `Eval`, exemplo:

```
Option Explicit

Dim numero
Dim codigo
Dim resultado

numero = 7
codigo = "numero * 4"
resultado = Eval(codigo)

MsgBox resultado
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que para passar aspas dentro de aspas é necessário escapa-las primeiro, ou seja isso não vai funcionar pois vai causar erro de sintaxe:

```
Dim str

str = "MsgBox "Olá mundo""

Execute(str)
```

Em VB é necessário passar uma aspa a frente de cada asp que desejar escapar, assim:

```
Dim str

str = "MsgBox ""Olá mundo"""

Execute(str)
```

Veja que para aplicar as aspas dentro da string foi necessário transformar isto:

```
"Olá mundo"
```

Em:

```
""Olá mundo""
```

Desta forma ocorre o escape das aspas.

---

O uso do `Execute` o Gabriel já mostrou em um .vbs parece que funciona normal, em "macros" do office não sei como se comporta, todavia como alternativa tem esta sugestão do SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43217874/1518921 (um exemplo em Excel)

```
Sub StringExecute(strToExecute As String)
    Dim vbComp As Object
    Set vbComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    vbComp.CodeModule.AddFromString "Sub foo()" & vbCrLf & strToExecute & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
    Application.Run vbComp.name & ".foo"
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbComp
End Sub

Sub Testing()
    StringExecute "MsgBox ""Olá mundo"""
End Sub
```